# SSE core task scheduler startup problem in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, startup-error

Whenever I'm launching my eclipse IDE with my project workspace, there is one popup window showing some internal error with the task scheduler. I'm attaching the picture of that popup window here.

[image]

My project is all in java language and also uses spring boot in it.

The error says something like

*An internal error occurred during: "SSE core task scheduler startup"*

Sorry I'm not able to add a direct image for this as Stack overflow is not allowing me to do that.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today.

Updating Eclipse solved it for me:

Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Update

Answer (score 36):

Maybe a missing or an outdated plugin. You should verify your ICU4J plugin version (menu: Help -> About Eclipse IDE -> Installation Details -> plugins).
[image: eclipse plugins]

If "Eclipse Orbit" plugin version is older than "Unicode, Inc" version check for missing/outdated software site and add/update "Eclipse Orbit"  https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/2022-09.

Then check for new updates or install ICU4J.

[image: icu4j installation]

Comment: I can confirm, that was my issue. I had "Eclipse Orbit ICU4J Base 58.2.0.v20170418-1837 com.ibm.icu.base" installed. After updating it to 67.1.0.v20200706-1749 the problem went away.

Comment: I can confirm, this answer solved that problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Running with temurin-18.jdk on MacOS, stack below.

Offending call to new StringTokenizer(..):

https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting/+/refs/heads/master/core/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.sse.core/src/org/eclipse/wst/sse/core/utils/StringUtils.java#777

Looks like an errant import from com.ibm instead of java.util.StringTokenizer:

https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting/+/refs/heads/master/core/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.sse.core/src/org/eclipse/wst/sse/core/utils/StringUtils.java#27

> import com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer;

Stack:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2022-09-22 08:11:42.471
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "SSE core task scheduler startup".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.utils.StringUtils.unpack(StringUtils.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.getScannedProjects(TaskScanningJob.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.projectHasNotBeenFullyScanned(TaskScanningJob.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.addProject(TaskScanningJob.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.enqueue(TaskScanningScheduler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.startup(TaskScanningScheduler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.lambda$0(SSECorePlugin.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job$1.run(Job.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer cannot be found by org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_1.2.800.v202207121749
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: I am seeing this very same issue. I have see it on two different Macs this week, both running Eclipse with Amazon Corretto JDK17. I have done nothing this past week but fight this and NUMEROUS other Eclipse issues since the 2022-09 (4.25) update. Install, configure, delete, repeat, MANY TIMES. Things work briefly the Eclipse inexplicably deletes or modifies a preference and nothing works. I can't trust Eclipse to work.

Answer (score 3):

For me, Eclipse was *almost* working until these two updates occurred:

```
Mylyn WikiText  3.0.43.202209151832 org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn

M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 2.0.5.20220912-1211 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
```

The StringTokenizer error appeared immediately after Eclipse restarted.

(I emphasize *almost* because M2E was never copying the Maven Dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib of my configured server.)

Answer (score 3):

This error caused lot of issues to me like unable to open jsp editor in Eclipse, multiple crashes when autocomplete is selected.

This is what i did..

1. First go to `Menu Bar > Help > Install New Software > Manage Button` in Eclipse.
   Search for m2e. There may be one item with icon and without any name. Click on **edit** and then update the url to http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest . Click on **Add** and then **Apply and close** and then **Finish**.
2. As suggested by user [@EG-IT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18048232/eg-it),

Now Go to `Menu Bar > Help > Install New Software` in Eclipse. In the work with text area insert this link https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/2022-09.  If drop down menu appears then fine, If not add a space and press backspace now a drop down should appear.

Select the option with **orbit - https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/2022-09**

Click on the **Select All** button on the right and click **Next** button. Select all items if prompted to install. Agree to term and conditions, wait till updates are installed. Restart IDE.

If same error persists please update the Eclipse.

I hope this detailed explanation works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same thing from the below link, if you want to know more check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e)

Run the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe)
To do this, follow these steps:

Open an elevated command prompt. To do this, do the following as your appropriate:

If you are running Windows 10, Windows 8.1 or Windows 8, first run the inbox Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool prior to running the System File Checker.  (If you are running Windows 7 or Windows Vista, skip to Step 3.)

Type the following command, and then press Enter.  It may take several minutes for the command operation to be completed.

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Important: When you run this command, DISM uses Windows Update to provide the files that are required to fix corruptions. However, if your Windows Update client is already broken, use a running Windows installation as the repair source, or use a Windows side-by-side folder from a network share or from a removable media, such as the Windows DVD, as the source of the files. To do this, run the following command instead:

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess

Note: Replace the C:\RepairSource\Windows placeholder with the location of your repair source. For more information about using the DISM tool to repair Windows, reference Repair a Windows Image.

At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:

sfc /scannow

[image]

The sfc /scannow command will scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a compressed folder at %WinDir%\System32\dllcache.
The %WinDir% placeholder represents the Windows operating system folder. For example, C:\Windows.

Note Do not close this Command Prompt window until the verification is 100% complete. The scan results will be shown after this process is finished.

After the process is finished, you may receive one of the following messages:

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

This means that you do not have any missing or corrupted system files.

Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

To resolve this problem, perform the System File Checker scan in safe mode, and make sure that the PendingDeletes and PendingRenames folders exist under %WinDir%\WinSxS\Temp.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Details are included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

To view the detail information about the system file scan and restoration, go to How to view details of the System File Checker process.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

To repair the corrupted files manually, view details of the System File Checker process to find the corrupted file, and then manually replace the corrupted file with a known good copy of the file.

Comment: Please add the actual content to your answer instead of linking to it, because links get broken over time.